# Performance Improvement while joining one huge table with one small table

Tags: performance, join, teradata

I am trying to join 2 tables where table A is having 400 million records and table B is having around 50 records. When i am trying to join these tables its taking long time. The reason is I have PPI in table A on non-primary index column.

How can i improve performance in this case?

Comment: I am trying this join in Teradata

Comment: Do you jpin all rows or is there a selective Where-condition? What's the Explain plan? Probably duplicating the small table followd by a product join.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth for quick response. Applied join condition on primary index columns and there is no where condition involved

Comment: Can you show Explain?

Comment: The result goes into Spool 1 20 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs. The size of 21 Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 17 rows (1,683 22 bytes).
 The estimated time for this step is 20.14 seconds.

Comment: How long does this run and how many rows are returned? If it's a low number (e.g. only those 50 rows from table B) a Single Table Join Index might help. But you need to add stats which seem to be missing.#